# Using Capybara with PolymerJS and Chrome Selenium Driver

Tags: google-chrome, capybara, polymer

I'm trying to write tests for my application.  I'm using Capybara with the Selenium Driver with browser set to chrome.  When I hit my application, I see the top level custom element for my application, but I don't see anything as far as the shadow dom.  Before I go spelunking in Capybara and Selenium code, I thought I would post a question here.  Has anyone even tried this yet?  I understand what is happening (the shadow dom isn't populating in the HTML).  Is there a way to get to get the shadow dom to get populated.

Comment: I also faced with this problem today. In my case, we have a Custom element which contain a text field (i.e HTML "input"), and Capybara could not locate any "input" element at all.

Comment: You can use page.evaluate_script combine with a query script. I figured out a method to access username/password of a login form which nested deep into many Custom Element. And I was able to set value to username and password. Here is an example: document.querySelector('classroom-app').shadowRoot.children[1].childNodes[3].children[0].shadowRoot.children[1].children[0].children[1].children[0].children[1].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[1].value="test1@test.com"

Comment: The problem was, although the username/password are correct, it looks like these values only appears to be correct on the GUI only. Hence, I submit the form and it appears like EMPTY username/password was sent to server. Only when I use my hand to type on the keyboard, and edit both username/password then these values are submitted correctly.

Comment: It should also be noted that the Selenium binary Chrome driver now supports Shadow DOM (since Jan 28, 2015) :  http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.14/notes.txt